# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer CORS issue when accessing PDF

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

how do i address CORS issue

I have this code <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'http://xyz/signed/12172020.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true" height="100vh"> when i am running the code i get CORS error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at ' 'http://xyz/signed/12172020.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: Have you setup the CORS policy in your backend to access the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the good old CORS problem. It's a protection against hackers. As a side effect, it also drives developers nuts.

Have a look at https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/ for in-depth information and a solution. However, I'm not sure if Juri's proxy.conf.json file still works. When I needed it two days ago, I had to use a slightly different version:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
      "host": "www.beyondjava.net",
      "protocol": "https:",
      "port": 443
    },
    "secure": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```